# Error converting data types. CONVERT(money, char(10)'good')?

Tags: sql-server, types

I am trying to flag where ListPrice > 100 then 'good'.

```
SELECT          
bom.[ProductAssemblyID]             
,bom.[ComponentID]
,p.[Name]
,p.[ListPrice]

FROM        
[Production].[BillOfMaterials] bom      
right join [Production].[Product] p         
on bom.ProductAssemblyID = p.ProductID

Where 
[ProductAssemblyID] is not null 
and [ComponentID] is not null
and [ListPrice] = (case when [ListPrice]> 100 then (convert(money,char(10),'good')) end )
```

I get this error, yet my code has nothing to do with varchar()

> Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Line 16 Argument data type varchar is
>   invalid for argument 3 of convert function.

Comment: convertion getting failed at : (convert(money,char(10),'good'))

Comment: you are missing an else in the case statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all Read [CAST and CONVERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

```
(convert(money,char(10),'good')) is invalid.
```

because you are trying to `convert` '`good`'(`a string value`) to  `money`(`acceptable decimal/integer value`)

So, you need to try:

```
  SELECT          
    a.[ProductAssemblyID]             
    ,a.[ComponentID]
    ,b.[Name]
    ,b.[ListPrice]
    , CASE
        WHEN b.ListPrice > 100 THEN 'higher than 100'
        ELSE 'less than 100'
    END AS result

FROM [Production].[BillOfMaterials] a
RIGHT JOIN [Production].[Product] b         
ON a.ProductAssemblyID = b.ProductID

WHERE a.[ProductAssemblyID] is not null 
AND a.[ComponentID] is not null
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to make your "flag" a column in your `SELECT`, not a portion of your `WHERE` clause, like so:

```
SELECT          
    bom.[ProductAssemblyID]             
    ,bom.[ComponentID]
    ,p.[Name]
    ,p.[ListPrice]
    , CASE
        WHEN p.ListPrice > 100 THEN 'GOOD'
        ELSE ''
    END AS 'flag'

FROM [Production].[BillOfMaterials] bom         
RIGHT JOIN [Production].[Product] p         
ON bom.ProductAssemblyID = p.ProductID

WHERE [ProductAssemblyID] is not null 
AND [ComponentID] is not null
```